# EE's Native Image Manipulations Stored on S3 with Assets 2?

Tags: assets, image, s3

When storing images to S3 with Assets 2, is it possible to store the images created by ExpressionEngine's native image manipulation functionality to S3 as well, or must they be saved to a local directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image Manipulations with EE are directly tied to a File Upload preference - which is a local source item, not an S3 bucket.  I don't think that what you want is currently possible.

But, what I hear you saying is that you wish to use image manipulations and have those modified images uploaded/stored/referenced via S3.  Is that right?

Comment: Correct. We're currently using CE Image, and it's working really well, but, it creates redundant copies of the source and output images on the local server, per this thread: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5648/prevent-purge-local-caching-of-s3-files-with-ce-image

Comment: I'll send your idea for this to our team, Nick.  Thank you!

Comment: We really could use this, too. The problem I'm seeing is that if Assets is set to upload directly to S3, the native image manipulations don't create anything, so there aren't any modified images to upload.

Comment: Agreed, this feature would be a huge value to us since we run 3 app servers with images stored on S3.

Comment: Plus one on this... just discovered that using CE Image's AWS caching thing on an image slideshow of 30 files adds like 2 seconds to the page processing time over just serving the natively-resized-on-upload files from an EE upload directory. Would prefer to serve from S3, so combining on-upload resizing with S3 storage would be fantabulous!